# Laravel: Missing laravel_session cookie and xsrf token

Tags: php, laravel

> Im Using laravel 5.5 version.. after some sort of codings
> laravel_session and xsrf token missing .. i suspect because of my
> configurations? since i enabled recently the session encryption
>
> here is my config/session.php

```
 <?php
    
    return [
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Default Session Driver
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
        | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
        | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
        |
        | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
        |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
        |
        */
    
        'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Lifetime
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
        | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
        | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
        |
        */
    
        'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    
        'expire_on_close' => false,
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Encryption
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
        | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
        | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
        |
        */
    
        'encrypt' => false,
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session File Location
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
        | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
        | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
        |
        */
    
        'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Database Connection
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
        | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
        | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
        |
        */
    
        'connection' => null,
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Database Table
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
        | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
        | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
        |
        */
    
        'table' => 'sessions',
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Cache Store
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
        | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
        | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
        |
        */
    
        'store' => null,
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Sweeping Lottery
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
        | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
        | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
        |
        */
    
        'lottery' => [2, 100],
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Cookie Name
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
        | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
        | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
        |
        */
    
        'cookie' => env(
            'SESSION_COOKIE',
            str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
        ),
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Cookie Path
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
        | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
        | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
        |
        */
    
        'path' => '/',
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Session Cookie Domain
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
        | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
        | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
        |
        */
    
        'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | HTTPS Only Cookies
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
        | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
        | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
        |
        */
    
        'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | HTTP Access Only
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
        | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
        | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
        |
        */
    
        'http_only' => true,
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Same-Site Cookies
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
        | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
        | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
        |
        | Supported: "lax", "strict"
        |
        */
    
        'same_site' => null,
    
    ];
```

[image: Here is my application for login..]

Actions done:

composer update

php artisan config:cache

Here is my env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:nuZLkdIGss8dJNdo9pl7uWeAzO25dFMtzkcl9mXdIC0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rebirth
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
```

> As you can see no laravel session or xsrf token here.. Any help would be appreciated
> thanks

Comment: What does your env look like for the value's in the session config file?

Comment: Hello @Taacoo thanks for the response I updated my post(Hidden email and so forth)..

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Nope , I just created a new project instead and switch to 5.6.. I suspects either it is on my configs or just other laravel bug for 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),` around lines #165-170 in your `config/session.php` file.